# php var_dump not finishing XML

Tags: php, var-dump

So I have an xml file that was created as the return value from curl_exec. The problem is that it only outputs the first 2514 characters and then continues with a ...

Why is this? Is there any way for me to tell var_dump() to give me EVERYTHING?

Here is my code snippet:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($file_contents);
```

Thanks all

EDIT: This is even true when I use a web browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have xdebug installed it will truncate your var_dumps (in an effort to help prevent massive amounts of debug information from being printed to the screen.. possibly crashing your browser). Read http://xdebug.org/docs/display for the settings that will effect this.

> There is a number of settings that control the output of Xdebug's modified var_dump() function: xdebug.var_display_max_children, xdebug.var_display_max_data and xdebug.var_display_max_depth.

Comment: xdebug.var_display_max_data = 999999 should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Does using "View source" option in your browser solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

it wont. try use echo "".print_r($yourData);

or even better, write output for large data into files!